# Black box behind windows in Wayland

Tags: gnome, 17.04, wayland

Using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with Wayland session, new windows and windows being re-sized get a flash of a black mask before they sort themselves out and resolve to pleasant shadows.

Demo screencast:

[image: screencast showing problem]

This does not happen in the default session using xorg. I've using "Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)".

Comment: I have the same issue. Not sure why

Comment: @Niklas upvote the question might mean more people see it and maybe someone can answer it?